# Join two tables with same ID and merge ID columns

Tags: mysql

This is probably a pretty simple question, but most of the searches I do have to do with merging rows (not merging columns) or concatenating them.

I want to join two tables on an ID column, but I only want it to return a single ID column.

Example:

Table 1:

```
ID|Data1|Data2
```

Table2:

```
ID|Data3|Data4
```

I want it to return:

```
ID|Data1|Data2|Data3|Data4
```

EDIT:

I realize I can specify every column, but there are actually closer to 50 columns that I'm bringing over and I would prefer not to have to specify every single one. Is there a way to do this without specifying each column to bring over from the query?

I believe natural join is what I need, but see this error I'm getting:

```
SELECT *
FROM allqachecklists t1
WHERE t1.IsIncorrect=1
NATURAL JOIN (SELECT QAID, PMC, SiteName, Submitter, QAer FROM qabin.allqas) t2
```

1 errors were found during analysis.

Unrecognized keyword. (near "NATURAL" at position 59)

Comment: Read up on `JOIN` - https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/joins.php

Comment: I like the venn diagram approach for explaining joins: https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: With your updates: move the where clause to after t2.  SELECT, FROM, JOINs, WHERE, GROUP BY, HAVING, ORDER BY,  LIMIT(not all engines).... Order of each statement is important to the compiler.  Oddly it doesn't process the data in this order though :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A natural join would allow you to select * from both tables and join on the key. These two columns are then returned as ONE in the result set; provided no other columns are named the same in both tables.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 A 
NATURAL JOIN Table2 B
```

An example can be found: http://rextester.com/FNT36037

mySQL [Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) state:
...

Natural joins and joins with USING, including outer join variants, are processed according to the SQL:2003 standard:

Redundant columns of a NATURAL join do not appear. 
...

With your edit to question: we can modify your SQL to the below.

```
SELECT *
FROM allqachecklists t1
NATURAL JOIN (SELECT QAID, PMC, SiteName, Submitter, QAer FROM qabin.allqas) t2
WHERE t1.IsIncorrect=1
LIMIT 10
```

Joins then where clause; though careful with outer joins as the limits on the table not having all records need to be put on the join or the outer join will behave like an inner.

Comment: I think this is close to what I want, but it's not letting me use the natural keyword for some reason - at least not with a subquery

Comment: The example in rextester works right?  So it has to be a syntax error or natural join isn't supported in your mysql version.

Comment: Note: natural joins are risky as if table structure changes, they can break your queries.  Inner join is prefered. and given this example you could just `t1.*, t2.QAID, t2.PMC, t2.SiteName, t2.Submitter, t2.QAer`

Comment: Yea I'm having an issue again - I ran the query, it worked, but I don't recall exactly how I did it - I'm trying to limit it to 10 rows and the limit keyword isn't working now. I swear it worked once, but I didn't save the query after I ran it FFS x.x I may just end up specifying all 50 columns or whatever - it's just ridiculous that I would have to do that.

Comment: It helps us help you if you provide sample data and ddl's (your create table statements) for the table with expected results.  You can build a sample set in rextester or sqlfiddle or just post it in your original question.  all of this helps us ensure we understand your question, and that you do as well :P

Comment: Np, you've helped enough - I have a checklist with questions and I'm trying to get all of the questions that are incorrect, but then I want to join who posted it and who checked it, but it's in a different table - they are joined using QAID - but I just wanted to return 1 QAID - since it's so annoying to do in MYSQL I'm just going to alias the second one I think (`QAID2`) and then ignore it in my javascript/php.

Comment: Natural Join seems like exactly what I needed and it looks like it works - but now LIMIT keyword isn't working - it's returning hundreds of rows (I just want to see 10 examples in this case). Wondering what other oddities it will have

Comment: Limit will work.  do you have a misplaced ; ending before the limit or something?  just modify my example in rextester and add a limit after the natural join of 1.  only 1 record returned! http://rextester.com/GMU71009 example limit iwth natural join 2 should have been returned but only 1 due to limit... though limit w/o an order by makes no sense.

Comment: No it's very frustrating - I marked your answer correct as soon as I tweaked it slightly and ran a query that returned 10 rows. Now I am running yours exactly and it's returning 300 rows. There is no `;` - I can't believe I didn't copy the final query that worked - no clue why it's giving me trouble now.

Comment: `Showing rows 0 - 299 (300 total, Query took 0.3450 seconds.)`
`SELECT * FROM allqachecklists t1 NATURAL JOIN (SELECT QAID, PMC, SiteName, Submitter, QAer FROM qabin.allqas) t2 WHERE t1.IsIncorrect=1 LIMIT 10`

Comment: Anyway, I don't want to bug you anymore - you've been very helpful. Just what I get for trying to do work on monday morning - thanks again for your help and have a great day :)

Comment: Very odd... Limit 10 there should do it.

Comment: Yea I'm using PHPMyAdmin - thought maybe it would be a setting that was ignoring the limits, but it works just fine with a different query. `Showing rows 0 - 9 (10 total, Query took 0.0035 seconds.)`
`SELECT * FROM allqachecklists WHERE 1 LIMIT 10` Oh well, I'm done fighting it - just going to do it the long weird select every individual column way - I'm certain NATURAL JOIN is what I was looking for so thanks for showing me that

Answer (score 2):

This is waht you need

```
SELECT table1.ID,table1.Data1,table1.Data2,table2.Data3,table2.Data4
FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.id
```

Comment: This can work, yea, but there are more like 50-100 columns. I would prefer to just select them all but merge the ID column and not have to specify every single one.

Comment: alias the tables to save typing! and improve readability.  you can also do `Select a.*, b.*` but same named columns will get duplicated.

Comment: Just do what @xQbert says, you will have two ID columns, but they will be the same value so it's ok.

Answer (score 1):

Sound like a pretty straight forward inner join:

```
select A.ID, data1, data2, data3, data4 from A 
inner join B ON A.ID = B.ID
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without specifying every single column? There are actually more like 50-100 columns being returned.

Comment: Do you really need to return all 100 columns?  Seldom are all needed at once; but if they are you can use a `select *` or `select a.*, b.*`

Comment: Right, but if I use `SELECT *` then I end up with two ID columns - and yes I need every single one. This query works because he specifies only a single ID in the select statement.

Comment: Then you have to select each column individually.  There isn't a * except.  You could use a `natural join` instead of `inner` since both are named ID and you'd only get 1 id column back; but any same named columns would be problematic

Comment: Is there a way to select everything that is NOT a specific column? Then I could alias the second Id away I suppose :\

Comment: Since you only want one of the ID columns, you have to specify all columns individually.

Comment: except if you use a natural join; but be careful that no other columns are named the same in the tables. Consider: http://rextester.com/FNT36037

Comment: @xQbert that might be exactly what I'm looking for - is it `NATURAL JOIN` ?

Comment: rextester link above gives you a good example.  Notice f in the second table isn't duplicated because the column names are the same in both result tables and it's using the natural join

Comment: @xQbert you should post this as answer - I think this is what I needed

Comment: @xQbert it doesn't like the keyword natural when I try to use it x.x i'm messing with it